# akka stream kafka web socket clients stop receiving messages after 30 seconds of inactive period

Tags: scala, websocket, apache-kafka, akka, akka-stream

I want to read messages from a Kafka topic and send to web socket clients. I created a sample web socket server app using akka-stream-kafka.

I am using kafka-console-producer script to send messages to kafka topic.
Works fine, browser clients receive data from kafka topic over web socket.

If I do not send messages to the topic for period of 30 seconds, the server gives following message,

[KafkaServiceActor-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://KafkaServiceActor/system/kafka-consumer-2] Message [akka.kafka.KafkaConsumerActor$Internal$Stop$] without sender to Actor[akka://KafkaServiceActor/system/kafka-consumer-2#-1039823616] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.

After this message the web socket client do not get any new messages from Kafka topic. I clients need to reconnect to start getting messages from topic.

Appreciate any feedback.

```
val incoming = Sink.foreach(println)

def kafkaOut(clientId: String) =
  Consumer.plainSource(consumerSettings.withGroupId(clientId), Subscriptions.topics(KAFKA_TOPIC)).map {
    r =>
      val value = r.value()
      TextMessage(value)
  }

val requestHandler: HttpRequest => HttpResponse = {
  case req @ HttpRequest(GET, Uri.Path("/stream"), _, _, _) =>
    req.header[UpgradeToWebSocket] match {
      case Some(upgrade) => {
        val clientId = "akka-kafka-client-" + clientIdGen.nextInt(1000) 
        upgrade.handleMessagesWithSinkSource(incoming, kafkaOut(clientId))
      }
      case None => HttpResponse(400, entity = "Not a valid websocket request")
    }

  case req: HttpRequest =>
    req.discardEntityBytes() //drain the incoming http entity stream
    HttpResponse(400, entity = "Unknown service")
}

private def startServer(): Unit = {
  val serverSource: Source[Http.IncomingConnection, Future[Http.ServerBinding]] =
    Http().bind(interface = HOST, PORT)

  bindingFuture =
    serverSource.to(Sink.foreach { connection =>
      connection.handleWithSyncHandler(requestHandler)
    }).run()

  log.info(s"Server online at http://localhost:9000/")
}
//I do not get any error with following changes 
def kafkaOut(clientId: String) = {

val (queueSource, futureQueue) = peekMatValue(Source.queue[String](10, OverflowStrategy.fail))

futureQueue.map { queue =>
  Consumer.plainSource(consumerSettings.withGroupId(clientId), Subscriptions.topics(KAFKA_TOPIC))
    .runForeach(t => queue.offer(t.value()))
}

queueSource.map(x => TextMessage(x))
}                                                                                                                
//T is the source type, here String
//M is the materialization type, here a SourceQueue[String]
def peekMatValue[T, M](src: Source[T, M]): (Source[T, M], Future[M]) = {
val p = Promise[M]
val s = src.mapMaterializedValue { m =>
  p.trySuccess(m)
  m
}
(s, p.future)
}
```

Comment: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/timeouts.html You may want take a look at `akka-http`'s `idle-timeout` setting

Comment: Thanks @jilen. I do not get the error after i added the changes (in the edited). The time-out setting also helps with keeping the connection open longer.